# Multi Wordpress install Apache2 config

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I have multiple instances of Wordpress installed on a single server.

the file structure is like this:

`var/www/siteone.com/app/...wp install`
`var/www/sitetwo.com/app/...wp install`
`var/www/sitethree.com/app/...wp install`

in the respective *sites-available* *.conf files, I have this:

**000-default.conf**

```
DocumentRoot /var/www
```

**siteone.com.conf**

```
ServerName siteone.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/siteone.com/app
ServerAlias www.siteone.com
```

I've run `a2ensite siteone.com` and reb0oted apache.
As I'm still setting it up, I don't actually have domain mapped to the ip so I am attempting to access the site with `http://123.456.789.0`

How does apache map that to the sub dir? Does it become `http://123.456.789.0/siteone.com`? Every combination I try yields a failure to respond from the server. Am I missing a step? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add  `123.456.7.8 siteone.com` to your vhost?

Comment: no. If I do, what would the new url be in theory?

Comment: U can visit the siteone.com like if it is a real domain. And by vhost I mean on your local machine not on the server. What kind of machine are you? Windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: I'm on a mac. Shouldn't I be able to call up the site from the server by using the right url structure?

Comment: No, type `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add this code `123.456.7.8 siteone.com` then you can access the `siteone.com` via the browser. How this works is Apache will look to you request and shows the correct website.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Do the conf files look correct? I still get an unresponsive  site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151076/discussion-between-motleydev-and-justkidding96).